# difficulty in downloading software packages

Tags: downloads

I am not able to download software sometimes it shows available from the "main source"and sometimes it shows available from the "universal source" plz. help

Answer (score 0):

@deepak, could I assume that you are using the Ubuntu software center? If not, could clarify the question? Once in the Ubuntu Software Center, click Edit, and then click on Software sources and ensure that all sources are checked on that screen.